# how can I make dotdotdot plugin work in two divs with same ID?

Tags: html

http://jsfiddle.net/qEsQf/

```
<div id = "multilinedText">
This text is so big that it won't fit in a single line, maybe we could use two lines or even three!
</div>
<div id = "multilinedText">
This text is so big that it won't fit in a single line, maybe we could use two lines or even three!
</div>
```

here is the fiddle ! I'm not being able to load this on several divs! is there a solution or other plugin that does the same??

Best regards

Comment: IDs **must** be unique. Try classes instead.

Comment: good point, but I'm not being able to run this plugin on classes.

Do you have a sugestion?

Comment: HTML 4.01 specification says ID must be document-wide unique .......          HTML 5 specification says the same thing but in other words. It says that ID must be unique in its home subtree which is basically the document if we read the definition of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As j08691 suggest : http://jsfiddle.net/qEsQf/344/

```
$(".multilinedText").dotdotdot();
```

Comment: are you sure you have it working? it's not working on my browser

Comment: ok, changed to my laptop and it's working... Thanks ! I dunno why it doesn't on my pc probably it's old software or so

Comment: @FilipePihh it's working.what browser you are using.